# Java command not working when adding a classpath

Tags: java, windows, cmd, java-7

Currently trying to run a java file that requires a jar package, typed the javac command and it was all good, when trying to run

```
java javafile
```

i get error that i'm referencing classes not available (because they are in the jar package), so I found out I've to add the jar package as classpath like so

```
java -cp "..\file.jar": javafile
```

but only to get an error

```
Error: could not find or load main class javafile
```

tried to find solutions for this, but they all say I'm writing the filename or packages or path wrong, it is not in a package, and i already ran it without the classpath, so why it fails to load now?

Comment: You need to add both the jar and the current directory if you are running a class from the current directory. E.g. `-cp ..\file.jar:.`. Note that if the class is called `javafile` then it's bad naming. It should be both meaningful, and start with a capital letter.

Comment: The Windows version of Java uses `;` as a path separator. You are trying to use `:` so java is looking in a non-existent file called `..\file.jar:`.